# mysql zero and empty values

Tags: php, mysql

In a table I have value `zero(0)` in a particular field in some records but when I am using a query to avoid empty values in this field, it is not considering field with 0 value. How to overcome this?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM wr
WHERE   dir <> ''
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(date, ' ', time)) 
BETWEEN '$time_start_unix' AND '$time_end_unix
```

the field dir is a decimal filed with two decimal point. Values can be blank as well as `0 to 360`. I do not want blank or empty values but need zero value records

Comment: Do yourself a huge favour and store date and time as a single entity.

Comment: I cannot replicate this behaviour. Do you mean NULL instead of 'blank'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `dir` is a numeric, non-nullable, column, then the only values you should *ever* see are numbers.  Therefore the `WHERE` condition:

```
WHERE dir <> ''
```

makes no sense at a high level, because you are trying to compare a number against an empty string.  At the database level it appears that MySQL is returning false for `x <> ''` whenever `x` is zero, and true otherwise.  Hence, your 2 records with `dir` having a zero value are being filtered out.  There are *no* empty records with regard to the value of `dir`.  However, since you set a default value to `0.0`, if you see a zero value, and nothing in your business logic would update with this value, then the following query *might* be what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM wr
WHERE dir <> 0.0 AND
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(date, ' ', time))
      BETWEEN '$time_start_unix' AND '$time_end_unix
```

I have created a Fiddle demonstrating this this here:

## SQLFiddle

Comment: I did not understand. In the above sql, I want all records where dir is not empty.

Comment: Are you telling us that `dir` could be empty(`''`) _or_ it could be `NULL`?

Comment: it could be empty or value 0 to 360. NULL is not allowed

Comment: Your current query already allows zero values, since they are not empty.  Are you sure your `WHERE` clause would allow any such values through in the first place?

Comment: Though my current query is structured to include zero values, I found that it is not happening. It exclude zero values. That puzzles me,

Comment: This makes me suspect that you are _seeing_ zero values but the underlying data might actually be `NULL`.  When you said `NULL` is not allowed, does this mean the column is not nullable, or that in your mind you don't want `NULL` values?

Comment: If I use this query "SELECT * FROM wr WHERE   dir ='' AND date between '2016-07-15' and '2016-07-18' " it shows  93 records all having some values 1 to 360. But there are two more records which having dir=0 which is not showing up. Instead if I use dir=0 in the above query, it shows 2 records

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121138/discussion-between-mansoondreamz-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
SELECT
    *
FROM wr
WHERE   dir IS NOT NULL
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(date, ' ', time)) 
BETWEEN '$time_start_unix' AND '$time_end_unix
```

You will have 0 in your result set.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL comparing zero to a string 0 = "any string" is always true! so we need to CAST it.

```
WHERE CAST(dir AS CHAR) <> ''
```